# How to edit a dataframe row by row while itterating?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

So I am using a script to read a CSV and create a data frame from which it then scrapes price data using tickers from said data frame. The original data frame has the following columns, note NO 'Price'.

```
df.columns = ['Ticker TV', 'Ticker YF', 'TV Name', 'Sector', 'Industry',  'URLTV']
```

I've printed the below first couple of outputs from my "updated" data frame

```
 Ticker TV Ticker YF  ...  URLTV     Price
1         100D    100D.L  ...  URL       NaN
2         1GIS    1GIS.L  ...  URL       NaN
3         1MCS    1MCS.L  ...  URL       NaN
...          ...       ...  ... ...      ...
2442         ZYT     ZYT.L  ...URL       NaN
100D.L       NaN       NaN  .. NaN  9272.50
1GIS.L       NaN       NaN  ...NaN  8838.50
1MCS.L       NaN       NaN  ...NaN  5364.00
```

As you can see it's not working as intended I would like to create a new column with the name of Price and attach each price with the correct ticker so 100D.L should be 9272.50 then when the script iterates to the next ticker it adds the next price value to 1GIS and so forth.

```
tickerList = df['Ticker YF']
for tick in tickerList:
    summarySoup = getSummary(tick)
    currentPriceData = priceData(summarySoup)
    print('The Price of '+tick+ ' is '+str(currentPriceData))
    df.at[tick,'Price'] = currentPriceData
```

Answer (score 0):

tick is just the value from your 'Ticker YF' column. so you can use enumerate to get also the index. And if you want to access the former price to add them up you can then just use idx-1

```
tickerList = df['Ticker YF']
for idx, tick in enumerate(tickerList):
    summarySoup = getSummary(tick)
    currentPriceData = priceData(summarySoup)
    print('The Price of '+tick+ ' is '+str(currentPriceData))
    if idx!=0:
       df.at[idx+1,'Price'] = float(currentPriceData)+float(df.at[idx,'Price'])
    else:
       df.at[idx+1,'Price'] = float(currentPriceData)
```

A more "elegant" idea could be something like:

```
df["Single_Price"]=df["Ticker YF"].apply(lambda x: priceData(getSummary(x)))
```

to get the value of the single prices. And then create the next column with the added prices:

```
df["Price"]=df["Ticker"].apply(lambda x: df["Single_Price"][df["Ticker"]<x["Ticker"]].sum())
```

this will add up every Single_Price (df["Single_Price"]) from every row that is before your current row Ticker x (df["Ticker"] < x["Ticker"]) and creates a new column Price in your dataframe.

after that cou can simply delete the single prices if you don't need them with:

```
del df["Single_Price"]
```

Comment: I adjusted the code to 

            if idx!=0:
            df.at[idx,'Price'] = currentPriceData

as the code would add rows together producing weird outputs

    2         1GIS    1GIS.L  ...  URL  5364.008838.509272.50

but the problem now appears to be that it skips or doesnt recognise the first entry 
    The Price of 100D.L is 9272.50
this is the first output price value
The Price of 1GIS.L is 8838.50
this is the second

1         100D    100D.L  ...  URL  8838.50

yet this is the table output.

as you can see its appending for the next ticker. Any Ideas?

Comment: oh that output seems to happen because your data type isn't float but string, change to float(currentPriceData)+float(df.at[idx-1,'Price']) and in the else statement too, dont really know what you ment by the further explenation after that ^^'

Comment: table output should be
ticker 1 price 5000
ticker 2 Price 7000
ticker 3 price 8000

but instead its 

ticker1 price 7000
ticker 2 price 8000


so the price recorded in the df is for ticker+1 if that makes sense?

Comment: Ah i understand, that is because idx starts counting from 0 not from 1. i ll edit my first post ;) - btw if you dont want to add up the prices like i thought: then just go for df["Price"]=df["Ticker YF"].apply(lambda x: priceData(getSummary(x))) as suggested below - much faster and simpler!

Comment: I made the +1 adjustment and it still doesnt show the first one in the DF output it doesnt have price so could be a issue with that?

I changed the code to just have df["Price"]=df["Ticker YF"].apply(lambda x: priceData(getSummary(x)))

and it seems to break the script it shows the first scrape "The Price of 100D.L is 9272.50" but doesnt print the df and seems stuck?

Comment: df["Price"]=df["Ticker YF"].apply(lambda x: priceData(getSummary(x))) will replace the complete code so you can't print in that line and you wont have that for loop anymore. After that you can print your df like: print(df[["Ticker YF", "Price"]]) as a list or you itterate over the finished df like: for row in df.itterrows(): print('The Price of '+row["Ticker YF"]+ ' is '+row["Price"])                                                                        . after that - quick question do you want to add up the prices that ocured before like i thought?

Comment: No I just want each a price for each ticker. 

the script now goes way too slowly just because that 1 line? 
df['Price'] = df['Ticker YF'].apply(lambda x: str(priceData(getSummary(x))))
I think your original method with my edit for if idx!=0:
       df.at[idx+1,'Price'] = float(currentPriceData)
is the best way to go I just need to work out how to add the column price before the for loop starts

Comment: well that 1 line will be faster in the backround your for loop does the same, but more - it just computes everything at once - if you want the first element in the price column just go with df.at[0,"Price"] = your_first_price or "None" if you just want the column

Comment: Ok I think I didnt understand correctly that that line replaced the whole loop code. Thanks for clearing that up

Comment: ive implemented the code and works great until there is a error def priceData(summarySoup): try: currentPriceData = summarySoup.find_all('div', {'class':'My(6px) Pos(r) smartphone_Mt(6px)'})[0].find('span').text currentPriceData = currentPriceData.replace(",","") float(currentPriceData) except Exception: errors.append(tick) print("Error, "+tick) currentPriceData = 0 return currentPriceData I Used this in my original script but now it says tick is not defined how do I correct for this?

Comment: well you don't have a tick value anymore because you don't iterate over the dataframe per hand - i would need to see the complete code - so maybe add a answer or change your question above and add more information^^ '

Answer (score 0):

Assign price using [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas-dataframe-apply) method:

```py
df['Price'] = df['Ticker YF'].apply(lambda x: str(priceData(getSummary(x))))
```

Comment: Hi ive implemented your code and works great until there is a error

def priceData(summarySoup):
    try:
        currentPriceData = summarySoup.find_all('div', {'class':'My(6px) Pos(r) smartphone_Mt(6px)'})[0].find('span').text
        currentPriceData = currentPriceData.replace(",","")
        float(currentPriceData)
    except Exception:
        errors.append(tick)
        print("Error, "+tick)
        currentPriceData = 0
    return currentPriceData


I Used this in my original script but now it says tick is not defined how do I correct for this?

Comment: you are appending `tick` to errors list, but `tick` is not accessible in your `priceData function`. 
what you can do is pass `tick` to this function on call as a parameter. 
make changes in the apply method and price data definition as 
`apply(lambda x: str(priceData(getSummary(x),x)))`
`def priceData(summarySoup,tick)`